# sql doesn't wants to leave empty fields in a table empty when i call echo in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Whenever i call a SQL function it fills out everything but empty fields accordingly to id number where id number says which record of name, account it takes. SQL instead fills the empty fields with data from previous id record.
How to tell SQL to not fill the empty fields and leave them empty as they are ?

Comment: Show your code please, what you have, help us understand exactly what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want SQL to display NULL fields with NULL(empty)

Comment: ...and since the behavior you've described is not the "standard behavior" you have to show us a little self-contained, tested, copy&pastable example that exhibits the problem. Show us the code.

Comment: You people don't know much, you can't help me.

Comment: That's right, we don't know much ...about what your code is doing and where the problem is. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try it the other way round...
Here's an example that doesn't exhibit the behavior you've described

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'localonly', 'localonly'); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soTest (id int auto_increment, x varchar(16) NOT NULL, y varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, primary key(id))');
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO soTest (x,y) VALUES (1, NULL), (2,'foo'), (3, NULL), (4, 'bar')");

echo "test 1: \n";
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT id,x,y FROM soTest', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
  $y = is_null($row['y']) ? '--null--' : $row['y'];
  printf("  %s %s %s\n", $row['id'], $row['x'], $y);
}

echo "test 2: \n";
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT id,x,y FROM soTest WHERE id IN (1,3)', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
  $y = is_null($row['y']) ? '--null--' : $row['y'];
  printf("  %s %s %s\n", $row['id'], $row['x'], $y);
}
```

prints

```
test 1: 
  1 1 --null--
  2 2 foo
  3 3 --null--
  4 4 bar
test 2: 
  1 1 --null--
  3 3 --null--
```

Your code does something differently. What is it?